# adjusting table content with javascript by enumerating rows

Tags: javascript

I have a table row with 4 columns on my ecommerce site and I want to replace the content of 1st column if total amount in last column (TD class "total") is over 10 EUR.

How can I do this with javascript only, I guess somehow to enumerate through the table rows and look for a correct row (one with the last column class as total) and then access the content of 1st column on this row but how?

Comment: Why don't you do this from your server side code? If javascript is disabled in client browser then you will present him the wrong information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do easily with JQuery:

```
if (parseInt($('.total').text(), 10) > 10)
{
   $('#your_table_id td:first').html('your content here');
}
```

**Note:** You could use `text()` instead of `html()` if you are interested in textual contents.